# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) - firebase error whene sending data with fetch in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, http-status-code-401

I am using fetch `javascript` function in react to send form data to `firebase` but causing an error of 401, I used `firebase` free service made a `database` and copied the `URL` and pasted in fetch function also provided the object as second argument and set method as post

```
look at my function below:-

    function addMeetupHandler(meetupData) {
            fetch('https://react-getting-started-755d5-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/meetups.json',{
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(meetupData),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'applications/json'
                }
            })
            console.log(meetupData)
        }
```

Here is below I am using the `newmeetuppage` as a parent component of `newmeetupform`, and I used fetch function to send data to `firebase API`.

```
import NewMeetupForm from '../components/meetups/NewMeetupForm'
function NewMeetupPage() {
    function addMeetupHandler(meetupData) {
        fetch('https://react-getting-started-755d5-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/meetups.json',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(meetupData),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'applications/json'
            }
        })
        console.log(meetupData)
    }

    return <div>
        <h1>Add New Meetup</h1>
        <NewMeetupForm onAddMeetup={addMeetupHandler}/>
    </div>
}

export default NewMeetupPage;
```

Below is `newmeetupform` component which is child component of `newmeetuppage`.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import Card from '../ui/Card';
import classes from './NewMeetupForm.module.css'
function NewMeetupForm(props) {
    const titleInputRef = useRef();
    const imageInputRef = useRef();
    const addressInputRef = useRef();
    const descriptionInputRef = useRef();
    function submitHandler(event){
        // react will automatically pass the event object to the function that is executing, because of all those built in events like onclick onsubmit and all the other events to which we can listen for all thsoe events react will automatically pass an event argument into the function that is executed for those events
       event.preventDefault();

       const enteredTitle = titleInputRef.current.value;
       const enteredImage = imageInputRef.current.value;
       const enteredAddress = addressInputRef.current.value;
       const enteredDescription = descriptionInputRef.current.value;

       const meetupData = {
            title: enteredTitle,
            image: enteredImage,
            address: enteredAddress,
            description: enteredDescription,
       }

      props.onAddMeetup(meetupData);
    }
    return (
        <Card>
            <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <div className={classes.control}>
                    <label htmlFor="title">Meetup Title</label>
                    <input type='text' required id="title" ref={titleInputRef}></input>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.control}>
                    <label htmlFor="image">Meetup Image</label>
                    <input type='url' required id="image" ref={imageInputRef} ></input>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.control}>
                    <label htmlFor="address">Address</label>
                    <input type='text' required id="address" ref={addressInputRef}></input>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.control}>
                    <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea id="description" required rows="5" ref={descriptionInputRef}></textarea>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.actions}>
                    <button>Add Meetup</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </Card>
        )
}

export default NewMeetupForm;
```

Through this, I am getting below error:

```
Object
react-getting-started-755d5-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/meetups.json:1   
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

When clicking on `URL, its showing permission denied.

I hope the problem is understandable